# AVAudioEngine detachNode Crashes with 'required condition is false' Error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioengine

I'm working on an audio processing application using Swift and encountering an issue with **AVAudioEngine** when I try to detach an **AVAudioPlayerNode**. My application is a call simulator that plays audio files.

I've shared the relevant code snippets below.

Code for attaching and playing the node:

```
let audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL)
let audioFormat = audioFile.processingFormat
let audioFrameCount = UInt32(audioFile.length)
let audioFileBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity: audioFrameCount)!
try audioFile.read(into: audioFileBuffer)

if playerNode == nil {
    playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    audioEngine.attach(playerNode!)

    // Use the stored outputNode for connection
    if let outputNode = self.outputNode {
        audioEngine.connect(playerNode!, to: outputNode, format: audioFormat)
    } else {
        print("Output node is not initialized")
        return
    }
}

// Start the engine if it's not running
if !audioEngine.isRunning {
    try audioEngine.start()
}

// Schedule the buffer and play
playerNode?.scheduleBuffer(audioFileBuffer, at: nil, options: []/* .loops*/, completionHandler: nil)
playerNode?.play()
```

Code for ending the call and detaching the node:

```
if let playerNode = playerNode, audioEngine.isRunning {
    playerNode.stop()
    
    if audioEngine.attachedNodes.contains(playerNode), !playerNode.isPlaying {
        print("[endcall debug] list of nodes: \(audioEngine.attachedNodes)")
        audioEngine.detach(playerNode)
    } else {
        print("[endcall] node is busy")
        return
    }
}
```

However, when I try to detach the playerNode, the application crashes with the following error:

> 2023-11-17 14:20:17.372029+0100 CallSimulator[99266:3421546] [avae]
> AVAEInternal.h:76 required condition is false:
> [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1771:RemoveNode:
> ((graphNode->IsNodeState(kAUGraphNodeState_InInputChain) ||
> graphNode->IsNodeState(kAUGraphNodeState_InOutputChain)))] 2023-11-17
> 14:20:17.418217+0100 CallSimulator[99266:3421546] *** Terminating app
> due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason:
> 'required condition is false:
> (graphNode->IsNodeState(kAUGraphNodeState_InInputChain) ||
> graphNode->IsNodeState(kAUGraphNodeState_InOutputChain))'

I am unsure why this error occurs when detaching the node. Here's what I'm trying to understand and fix:

1. What could be causing this error when I try to detach the playerNode?
2. Is there a specific procedure I need to follow before detaching a node from AVAudioEngine?
3. Any suggestions or guidance on how to resolve or avoid this error would be greatly appreciated.
   Thank you for your help!

Comment: The sort of thing you want to detach is an effect node. I don't see why it makes sense to detach a player node.

Comment: It might help to include at least an outline of the whole “player” class that contains this code which might shed more light on the approach.  If you are really doing all that set up and tear-down everytime you want to play something, thats not very efficient. You could just have player.play(buffer) and have the engine and its attached node be persistent inside the class